# MySQL Row not deleting when working with a specific column

Tags: mysql, row, sql-delete

Whenever I try deleting a row from a table using one specific column `namee` it˙s executing the query but the `0 row(s) affected` appears, with other columns works just fine.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
idEmployee int primary key auto_increment,
namee varchar(150) not null,
surname varchar(150) not null,
Department_idDepartment int not null,
Specialisation_idSpecialisation int not null,
Type_Employee_idType_Employee int not null,
Address_idAdress int not null);

insert into employee values(40, 'Mary ', 'Fry', 60, 12, 2, 80);
insert into employee values(41, 'Zoran ', 'Poglajen', 61, 13, 2, 81);
insert into employee values(42, 'Branko ', 'Gabrovec', 62, 14, 3, 82);


SELECT* FROM employee;
DELETE FROM employee 
WHERE surname= 'Fry' 
AND Type_Employee_idType_Employee = 2 
AND namee = 'Mary'; 
/*-> doesn`t execute when working even just with namee */ 
SELECT* FROM employee;
```

Comment: update your question and add  your code ..

Comment: The code works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cBBnBGmrsGcJGfUmzzFdvJ/0

Comment: I work on MySQL Workbench: `17:11:16 DELETE FROM employee  WHERE surname= 'Fry'  AND Type_Employee_idType_Employee = 2  AND namee = 'Mary' 0 row(s) affected 0.016 sec
   `

Comment: Can you add your actual table definition exactly as MySQL gives it to you (e.g. the 1:1 output of `show create table employee`)? You may have an unexpected charset/colation for your column (I am thinking of one that doesn't pad spaces, e.g. binary). Or you may have an unprintable character at the end of entry in the database (`'Mary '` has something at the end, maybe it is not a space).

Comment: It seems like mysql is not automatically trimming (expected behaviour) what appears to be trailing space , which may indicate that it's not a space at all...Try select namee, length(trim(namee)) from employee and report back what you get for the mary row.

Comment: Pft, it was that space from the insertion. Thank you all so much!